# where I am wrong? creating labels dynamically c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, runtime

I created `labels` and `textboxes` dynamically . everything goes fine,but the second `label`  doesn't want to  appear at all. where i am wrong? this is my code in C#:

```
private void checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleDataReader reader;
    int x = 434;
    int y = 84;
    int i = 0;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        foreach (var itemChecked in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
        {
            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.Location = new Point(x + 100, y);
            NewLabel.Name = "Label" + i.ToString();
            Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.Location = new Point(x, y);
            tb.Name = "txtBox" + i.ToString();
            Controls.Add(tb);
            y += 30;
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT distinct data_type from all_arguments where owner='HR' and argument_name='" + itemChecked.ToString() + "'", conn);


            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                label[0].Text = reader["data_type"].ToString();
            }

            i++;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (conn != null)
            conn.Close();
    }
}

private void Procedure()
{
    string proc = "";
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        if (this.listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            proc = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("" + proc + "", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var itemChecked1 in checkedListBox1.Items)
        {
            Control[] txt = Controls.Find("txtBox" + i.ToString(), false);
            Control[] label = Controls.Find("Label" + i.ToString(), false);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("select distinct data_type from all_arguments where owner='HR' and argument_name=toupper("+itemChecked1.ToString()+")",conn));
            cmd.Parameters[":"+itemChecked1.ToString()+""].Value=label[0].Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":" + itemChecked1.ToString() + "", OracleDbType.Varchar2));
            cmd.Parameters[":" + itemChecked1.ToString() + ""].Value = txt[0].Text;

            i++;
```

Comment: view the html and verify that the label is there. If it is, use your browser's development tools to manually adjust the css. IE9 has decent built in tools, just press F12.

Comment: "where i am wrong?" Besides from the SQL injection, the magic variable names:  `int x = 434; int y = 84;`, and the fact that you're running a select statement for *every* checked item? And why do you create a label just to turn around and FIND it? To be blunt, I think you should describe what you are trying to do, and that way we can throw out this code and start over.

Comment: I managed to do it,by someone who posted here,but I don't know why he deleted the post. I replace the word label with something else in these 2 lines:                                                                                   Control[] label = Controls.Find("Label" + i.ToString(), false);     and                                                                      NewLabel.Name = "Label" + i.ToString();

Comment: Well,I have a checkedlistbox with all the parameters from a procedure from my oracle database. I want an user to select a parameter and to introduce some values in textboxes that are created at every item checked from checkedlistbox. Also,next to the textboxes,I want to be displayed the type of the parameter(varchar2,number..) in order the user to know what to write. Thank you!

Comment: @Madalina do not add explanation to comments.  Edit them into your question.

Comment: And why are you using `Control.Find()` to get the label that you just created 10 lines above?

Comment: Sorry,it is no need to use Control.Find.

Comment: @Madalina a good way to design dynamic controls is to build them in WinForms and then look at the generated code in the `yourform.designer.cs` page.
This page is essentially Visual Studio dynamically building controls for you, so you can use the code as an example (or copy paste it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the second Label has appeared. But its text is an empty string! So you will never see it.
Check the "data_type" returned by DB reader.